# Creating PrivateRoute with 'component' prop instead of 'render' prop

Tags: reactjs, react-router

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component, ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}

      // OPTION 1
      component={!loggedInUser ? <Redirect to="/login" /> : component}

      // OPTION 2
      render={()=>(!loggedInUser ? <Redirect to="/login" /> : component())}

    />
  );
};
```

Which of the above do you prefer and why? I found that I wasn't able to use the new useParam() hook with OPTION 2 because it told me I was using a hook outside of a functional component body.

Answer (score 0):

here is a good route gate that supports component, render, permission and redirect in case of missing the permission

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Redirect, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

/* eslint-disable no-nested-ternary */
const RouteGate = props => {
  const {
    component: Component,
    hasPermission,
    redirectTo,
    render,
    ...rest
  } = props;

  return (
    <Route
      render={() =>
        hasPermission ? (
          Component ? (
            <Component {...props} />
          ) : (
            render()
          )
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: redirectTo,
            }}
          />
        )
      }
      {...rest}
    />
  );
};

RouteGate.propTypes = {
  component: PropTypes.func,
  render: PropTypes.func,
  hasPermission: PropTypes.bool,
  redirectTo: PropTypes.string,
};

RouteGate.defaultProps = {
  hasPermission: true,
  redirectTo: '',
};

export default RouteGate;
```

an example of using it with the component:

```
<RouteGate
    path={paths.profile} // route of the profile, eg: /profile
    component={Profile} // component of the profile page
    hasPermission={isLoggedIn} // a flag in user selectors
    redirectTo={paths.login} // route of the login page eg: /login
/>
```

an example of it with the render:

```
<RouteGate
    path={paths.profile}
    render={() => <Profile />}
    hasPermission={isLoggedIn}
    redirectTo={paths.login}
/>
```

Comment: Do either of your options if the Profile component makes use of the new useParams hook in React Router 5.1?

Comment: I'm using, useHistory, useLocation, and useParams with no issue